# Blazor app crashing with 'Stack overflow' in output window - What is breaking IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, blazor-server-side

I'm building a Blazor app which occasionally stops working. The only indication of what is going wrong is a message in the output window from the 'ASP.NET Core Web Server' that says 'Stack overflow.'

[image]

Looking in the Event Viewer I can see a log for Application Error:

```
Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 10.0.19041.1, time stamp: 0x0cefd54e
Faulting module name: coreclr.dll, version: 4.700.20.41105, time stamp: 0x5f3397ec
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00000000002eff98
Faulting process ID: 0x5578
```

Searching Google just brings up the Stack Overflow website [which your currently looking at].
Debugging doesn't show anymore than just 'Stack overflow' in the output and nothing happens the page continues to load (not getting anywhere), and the debugger seems to continue debugging without doing anything.

How do I go about finding what is breaking IIS Express and crashing my app?

Comment: What do you mean by "Debugging doesn't help"? if it's "occasionally" stopping then it's your app that is crashing IIS.

Comment: @HMZ Debugging doesn't show anymore than just 'Stack overflow' in the output and nothing happens the page continues to load (not getting anywhere), and the debugging seems to continue debugging without doing anything.